# HTML and body height not covering entire page after trying various possible options for both HTML and body

Tags: html, css

I have tried various possible options for height to cover the entire page/document, but none of them worked. When i make use of relative positions for elements, then the height covers entire page, but I am looking for way to fill/cover the height of entire page making use of "absolute" position for elements in my html, as i don't want to affect the behaviour other parts

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 100% !important; 
}

body{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
  /* min-height: 100% !important; */
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
}

  #body-container{
    height:100%;
}
/* ------------------------------------header start---------------------------------*/
#header-id {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:3px;
  left:3px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #272822;
  width: 100%;
}
/* ------------------------------------header end---------------------------------*/
/* ------------------------------------fa fa-navicon and a fa-home start------------------------------------*/
.fa-navicon,
.fa-home {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.fa-home {
  background-color: #272822;
}

.fa-navicon {
  background-color: darkslategrey;
}

.fa-navicon:hover,
.fa-home:hover {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}
/* ------------------------------------fa fa-navicon and a fa-home end------------------------------------*/
/* ------------------------------------top navigation menu start------------------------------------*/
#topnav-id {
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #7a7777;;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px; 
  left:3px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 41px;

  /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
#topnav-id::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#topnav-id a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: #272822;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#topnav-id a:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
}

#topnav-id .icon {
  display: none;
}
/* ------------------------------------top navigation menu end------------------------------------*/
/* ------------------------------------side navigation menu type 2 start---------------------------------*/
#sidenav-container-id{
  width: 260px;
  top: 120.5px;
  left: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 9px 6px 12px;
  background-color:#272822;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border: 0px;
  width: 260px;
}

.dropdown-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sidenav-dropdown-content-class {
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.sidenav-dropdown-content-class a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 12px;
  background-color:darkslateblue;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.show {display: block;}

/* ------------------------------------side navigation menu type 2 end---------------------------------*/
/* ------------------------------------content start---------------------------------*/
#content-id {
  /* min-height: 100%; */
  margin-left: 260px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-right: 180px;
  background-color: #d1cdcd;
  /* height: 100%; */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

 #pre-id {
   height: 100%;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   display: inline-block;
} 
/* ------------------------------------content end---------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index-script.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body-container">
    <div id="header-id"></div>

    <div id="topnav-id" class="topnav-class">
      <i class="fa fa-navicon" onclick="openCloseHambugerMenu()" style="font-size:20px; color: white"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:20px; color: white"></i>
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
      <a href="#">Link3</a>
      <a href="#">Link4</a>
      <a href="#">Link5</a>
    </div>

    <div id="sidenav-container-id">

      <div id="sidenav-navigation-id" class="sidenav-navigation-class">

        <button id="button1" class="dropdown-btn"
          onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown1')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown1" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#Hi">Link</a>
          <a href="#Hi">Link</a>
          <a href="#Hi">Link</a>
        </div>
        <button id="button2" class="dropdown-btn"
          onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown2')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown2" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
        <button id="button3" class="dropdown-btn"
          onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown3')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown3" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
        <button id="button4" class="dropdown-btn"
          onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown4')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown4" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
        <button id="button5" class="dropdown-btn"
          onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown5')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown5" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
        <button id="button6" class="dropdown-btn"
          onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown6')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown6" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
        <button id="button7" class="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown7')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown7" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
        <button id="button8" class="dropdown-btn"
          onclick="toggleSidenavDropdown('dropdown8')">Outer Link</button>
        <div id="dropdown8" class="sidenav-dropdown-content-class">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div id="content-id" class="content-class">
      <h2>Content</h2>
      <pre id="pre-id">
              import java.io.*; 
              import java.util.*; 
  
              class ArrayListExample { 
                 public static void main(String[] args) { 
                // Size of the 
                // ArrayList 
                int n = 5; 
          
                // Declaring the ArrayList with 
                // initial size n 
                ArrayList<Integer> arrli 
                    = new ArrayList<Integer>(n); 
          
                // Appending new elements at 
                // the end of the list 
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
                    arrli.add(i); 
          
                // Printing elements 
                System.out.println(arrli); 
          
                // Remove element at index 3 
                arrli.remove(3); 
          
                // Displaying the ArrayList 
                // after deletion 
                System.out.println(arrli); 
          
                // Printing elements one by one 
                for (int i = 0; i < arrli.size(); i++) 
                    System.out.print(arrli.get(i) + " "); 
              } 
            } 
       </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using absolute positioning for layout is a horrible approach. You'll learn why eventually.

Comment: Add more content to your site or add a footer in the bottom so it looks like the page height is 100%

Comment: Is there any way to to cover 100% height for the page using absolute. I just have basic requirement and not looking for footer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/), like `vw` (view width) and `vh` (view height). To make an absolutely positioned `div` fill the whole screen, you'd do:

```css
.my-div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; // or wherever in the stack you want the layer
}
```

Comment: In order to provide 100vw or 100vh to any of my div, I at least need to have my parent i.e HTML or body to have 100% height in case of absolute postioning. But i am not able to fill entire body/page with 100% height.

Comment: Viewport units don't care what's inside the element they're applied to. It can be completely empty and it will still stretch to fit the specified size.